# Finding the x-value at a certain y-value on a ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am currently having some difficulties trying to find the Effective Concentration of 50% for one of my datasets. To shortly summarize what it is, it is data on how levels of glutathione in cells depleted from 100% when exposed to a substance known as HEMA.

```
GSH50 <- read.table("Master list for all GSH data T9 TVN.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";", dec = ",")
```

After some further subsetting, I end up with a plot like this
[GSH plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4K9n.png)

I have several more plots in addition to this, so I need to find the EC50 value for everyone so I can then compare them with each other (the problem is consistent on several plots, so if it can be fixed here it should be fixed on the others as well).

From an earlier dataset with almost the same setup (the only difference being x-axis values) I managed to get fairly correct EC50 using a setup like this:

```
HG <- approxfun(x, y)
optimize(function(t0) abs(HG(t0) - 50), interval = range(x))
```

Where I then got my EC50 value from the optimize function. However, it does not work on this data for some reason, as if I input the value from optimize, I end up getting [this GSH plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCDpx.png) instead.

If somebody has any idea how I can fix this issue, it would be most appreciated.

*Edit*

If you want a reproducible dataset I gathered the averages of the data, and as such the plot should still be similar to the GSH plots I have shown:

```
Concentration <- seq(from = 0, to = 9, by=1)
GSH <- c(100, 67.405, 47.78, 39.2325, 33.97, 28.435, 26.97, 24.5125, 23.5275, 21.565)
df <- data.frame(Concentration, GSH)
ggplot(df, aes(Concentration, GSH)) + geom_smooth()
```

I am quite certain that the dose is high enough to reach the lower level, but I have not stored the model somewhere. I hope the example data provided is enough.

*Edit2*

I should mention that the approx and optimize code does work for the example when we use geom_lines(), but for some reason, it is not as accurate on geom_smooth().

Comment: Do not forget that you must be sure that you tested a high enough dose so you can reach the lower stage of your model ; this is mandatory to estimate an IC50. Also, do you have an R object where this model is stored?

Comment: You' have a higher probability of a satisfying answer if you post a reproducible example, e.g, the 'dput' of some example data. ggplot is for plotting, not for predictions. Use Regression functions for that.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I have added an example dataset that at least is somewhat similar to my data. Hope this will make it easier to explain what I need to do.